# 仮想マシンをコピーしたときにyumで登録されたミラーリストに届かない

Tags: centos

Vmware Playerで仮想マシンを一台作成し(CentOS6.5)必要なパッケージを
yumでダウンロードしていました。これに関しては正常にダウンロードとインストールがおこなわれております。

仮想マシンを複数台で運用する必要がでてきて、先の仮想マシンのイメージをコピーして、yumでパッケージをダウンロードしようとしたところ、ミラーリストに通信ができず、エラーになってしまいます。

なお、コピーした仮想マシンですので、IPアドレスは元の仮想マシンとは変更し、/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rulesの記載もeth0をコメントアウトし、eth1の行をeth0に変更、MACアドレスの記載を/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0に反映し、物理マシンとの疎通(ping)もとれております。

仮想マシンをコピーしたときに、なにか設定を変更しなければいけない部分がありますでしょうか。(gpg-keyの部分など)

お手数ですがご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

```
[root@xxx ~]# yum list
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2a02:2498:1:3d:5054:ff:fed3:e91a: Network is unreachable"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=x86_64 error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2610:28:3090:3001:dead:beef:cafe:fed3: Network is unreachable"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=extras error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2a02:2498:1:3d:5054:ff:fed3:e91a: Network is unreachable"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=updates error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2a02:2498:1:3d:5054:ff:fed3:e91a: Network is unreachable"
 * base: centos.usonyx.net
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * updates: centos.usonyx.net
http://centos.usonyx.net/main/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.usonyx.net/main/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:240:bb8f::1:70: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:df0:2ed:feed::feed: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
        http://ftp.nara.wide.ad.jp/pub/Linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:200:0:1::800:21: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Trying other mirror.
http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/Linux/centos/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "Failed to connect to 2001:200:0:7c06::9393: Network is unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
```

【IPv6を無効化してもう一度】
下記のページを参考にipv6の無効化設定をおこないました。
http://unixlife.jp/linux/netwoork/ipv6-none.html

少しメッセージは変わったのですが、相変わらずエラーがでてしまいます。

[root@test etc]# yum list
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
12: Timeout on http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

[root@test etc]# ping mirrorlist.centos.org
PING mirrorlist.centos.org (108.61.16.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=167 ms
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=166 ms
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=166 ms
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=166 ms
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=166 ms
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=6 ttl=47 time=166 ms
^C
--- mirrorlist.centos.org ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5890ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 166.193/166.662/167.832/0.534 ms

ただ、少しpingのかえりが遅いので、これはipv6がまだ有効になっているということでしょうか。

Comment: ホストとしか通信できていない可能性はありませんか？例えばgoogleにpingは通るのでしょうか。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。googleにpingは通ります。
[root@test ~]# ping google.co.jp
PING google.co.jp (173.194.117.216) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nrt04s11-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.117.216): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=4.41 ms
64 bytes from nrt04s11-in-f24.1e100.net (173.194.117.216): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=2.44 ms
^C
--- google.co.jp ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1327ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.449/3.433/4.418/0.986 ms

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: VMWarePlayerで2つのVMの環境設定を見て、mac addressって変わってますか？

Comment: @豚吐露 さん
mac addressもかわっております。
HWADDR="00:0c:29:57:83:11"
HWADDR="00:0c:29:29:37:F7"

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーになるコマンドとその出力を本文に追記していただけませんか？

Comment: @unaristさん

エラーの追記の方おこないました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: IPv6で通信してますね。無効化してみると変わるかもです。

Comment: @take88さんの言う通りでIPv6を無効化しないとyumはきちんと機能できません。これが仮想マシンだから起きることなのか元々そういうものなのかは知らないのですが、自分の経験で言うと、仮想マシンで動かした場合はIPv6を有効にしたままではほぼ機能したことがないです。

Comment: @take88さん
情報ありがとうございます。
ipv6の無効化を行ってみましたが、まだエラーが発生するようです。
本文の方に追記しました。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: http://mirrorlist.centos.org/
ここにアクセスできていないと言うエラーですよね。DNSの設定とか？
dig mirrorlist.centos.org 　できちんとIP取れますか？

Comment: @TomohiroObara さん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。IPとれます
[root@test yum.repos.d]# dig mirrorlist.centos.org
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.6 <<>> mirrorlist.centos.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53748
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mirrorlist.centos.org.         IN      A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mirrorlist.centos.org.  127     IN      A       108.61.16.227
mirrorlist.centos.org.  127     IN      A       84.22.180.89
mirrorlist.centos.org.  127     IN      A       88.150.173.218

Comment: yum だけプロキシ経由で接続しようとしているとか。
環境変数 http_proxy, https_proxy や /etc/yum.conf を確認してください。

Comment: >プロキシ経由　　　   それっぽいかもしれませんね。http://kajuhome.com/patio_thread/1638.shtml これに似てるような気もするし。

Comment: 念の為に、ipv6を無効化するのに何をしたのか具体的に明記したほうがよいかもしれないですね。/etc/sysctl.conf を操作したのか、それとも他の方法をとったのかがわかりません。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya さん
プロキシ経由でないか、http_proxy,https_proxyを確認しましたが、そのような記載は見当たりません。/etc/yum.confもなにも修正を加えていない状態です。

Comment: @cul8erさん
IPv6の無効化に関してですが、/etc/sysconfig/networkにNETWORKING_IPV6=noを加えたのと/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0にIPV6INIT=noを加えたのみです。

Comment: なんでしょうね。単に遅いだけの可能性もあるので `yum clean all` でキャッシュクリアと、`/etc/yum.conf` に `timeout=300' という風にタイムアウト時間を書いてみると現象変わりませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状で、mirrorlist.centos.org に ping は通るけれど HTTP でアクセスできないという状況ですね。
yum の問題なのかネットワーク的な問題なのか切り分けたいと思います。
下記はすべて応答がありますでしょうか。タイムアウトになりますでしょうか。

```
curl 'http://www.google.com'
curl --noproxy www.google.com 'http://www.google.com'
curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os'
curl --noproxy mirrorlist.centos.org 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ipv6を確実に無効化するには、[CentOSのwiki](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6#head-d47139912868bcb9d754441ecb6a8a10d41781df)に従うのが良いと思います。
私の経験に限ったことですが、VirtualBox + Vagrant を使った時にこの方法でIpv6を無効化すると上手くyumが動くことが大半でした。使用している環境がVMWarePlayerという点が違うので、必ずこの方法が上手くいくという保証はないですが、試してみても損はないかと思います。

> adding the following to /etc/sysctl.conf:
>   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6
>   = 1

この対応をした後で、

> sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1 sysctl -w
>   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1

とし、

その後に書かれた**additional note** の内容に従うのが良いと思います。特に2と3はやっておいた方が良いと思います。